# Firebase's Realtime Database's event listener's handler executes itself infinitely

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I found `next` executing itself infinitely. I think this is an abstraction of my code that replicates the problem:

```js
function next() {
  game.set(newObj)
}
game.child(`user1`).orderByKey().on(`value`, next);
```

The solution was to insert a remove the event listener:

```js
game.child(`user1`).orderByKey().off() //new
function next() {
  game.set(newObj)
}
game.child(`user1`).orderByKey().on(`value`, next);
```

My initial understanding was `ref.orderByKey().on('value', ...)` executed its handler once. Is there anything you can see here that explains why the handler executed infinitely?

If not, perhaps another piece of code was responsible - like one of the `child_changed` event listeners I have. My `child_changed` listeners all listen for a change in various parts of `game`. Surely updating `game` to a new object would trigger them. However, none of their callbacks are `next` so I think they don't play a role in retriggering `next`.

Answer (score 0):

> My initial understanding was `ref.orderByKey().on('value', ...)` executed its handler once. Is there anything you can see here that explains why the handler executed infinitely?

No, that's exactly the way it's supposed to work.  A listener attached using `on()` will be invoked every time the data is seen to change.  It will continue to do so until the listener is removed.  To do that, you must call `off()` *after* you call `on()`.

If you want to [execute a query just once](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once), use `once()` instead of `on()`.

Comment: i) `A listener attached using on() will be invoked every time the data is seen to change` - even for every different type of event (e.g. `'value', 'child_added', 'child_removed' 'child_changed'`? ii) `once()` seems handy but won't the listener still be there? Can this cause any problems a listener still being there?

Comment: Yes, for every type of event.  You should remove the listener when it's no longer needed in order to avoid potential problems.